# How assign or modify variable in Embedded Chat Labels {0}

Tags: customlabel, chat, embedded

I'm trying to add a custom variable to the "Embedded Chat" labels, but I don't understand how the {0} variable works, when I enter the chat it returns the first name plus the first letter of the last name, I want to try to modify it and not show me the last name.

I'm looking for some information but I can't find anything about this {0}, which is supposed to be Custom Labels, but I still don't know how to modify or reassign the value.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Live Agent (Embedded Chat) will return the full first name and last name initial as you are seeing.

Currently, for your requirement, you can go into `Setup > Chat > Chat Agent Configurations` and click edit on your configuration. You will see a field called "Custom Agent Name" where you can set it directly. You can also click its below to see available merge fields. For example, for first name only it would be `{!User_FirstName}`

Regarding the other Embedded Chat labels,in the UI you can write in the input box. For now, think of that symbol as a variable that you can replace with how you define the variable. Let me know in case of additional queries.